# how to put 4 image side by side with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

hello i want to put 4 image side by side with bootstrap 
with that code only 2 image puts side by side

```
   <div class="col-md-6">
       <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="inn_logo" /></a>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
       <a href="#" ><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="ccs_logo" /></a>
   </div>
```

i want to put 4 images side by side
how can id o it?

Answer (score 4):

Change your code so that it looks like this:

```
       <div class="col-md-3">
           <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="inn_logo" /></a>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-3">
           <a href="#" ><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="ccs_logo" /></a>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-3">
           <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="inn_logo" /></a>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-3">
           <a href="#" ><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="ccs_logo" /></a>
       </div>
```

the class has to be "col-md-3"

Answer (score 1):

Use col-md-3.

Bootstrap grid is divided in 12 cells. If you say that a div has class "col-md-1" it will use 1/12 of the width of the parent element.
If you want a full width row then it should have the class col-md-12.

Please remember that md stands for medium. There are other sizes as well you should be aware of.